# Splitting data frame in r into two

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has one column 'Date2' as modulus of 5 of another data column 'Date'. I want to split data into two data frames, one containing all values where modulus is 0 and 2nd all others.

Here is my code that is working on this reproducible code. Though as I have to apply it on a big data, I want to know it is appropriate way for this purpose.

Here is my code:

```
DD<-seq(as.Date("2019/01/01"), by = "day", length.out =31) #creating data for df
DD<-DD
DD2 <- data.frame("Date"=DD, var = c(1:31)) # reproducible df for testing
DD2<-DD2
DD2<-DD2%>%
mutate(Date2=mday(Date)%%5)# getting modulus of Date col in Date2 col
DD2

D3<-split(DD2, DD2$Date2==0) #all records with 0 remainder of 5
D4<-split(DD2, DD2$Date2!=0) # all other records 
D3
D4
```

Comment: You don't need two splits, the `D3` is essentially splitting into a `list` of 2 where 'Datee2' is 0 and all others.  Then, extract the `list` elements with `[[`

Comment: @akrun, sorry, I think Bec of C style comments I put, error are. I corrected

Comment: @akrun: you are right. Can you please tell how to use list element here to extract other.

Comment: I am not sure why you need to `split` here.  Wouldn't this be good as a grouping column `DD2 %>% mutate(new = as.integer(!mday(Date) %% 5))`

Comment: I think this is better you mentioned now. Though I think extracting list can be like: 
D3_['FALSE']
D3_['TRUE']

Comment: `DD<-DD` and `DD2<-DD2` do nothing.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: I think before these are not saved, after they are saved and var are available in the env.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to  `split`, we can also use `group_split`

```
DD2 %>%
      group_split(new = as.integer(!mday(Date) %% 5))
```

Or with `split`

```
DD3 <- split(DD2, DD2$Date2==0)
```

and then extract the elements with `[[`

```
DD3[["TRUE"]]
DD3[["FALSE"]]
```

But, it could be also created as a grouping variable instead of splitting into multiple datasets

```
DD2 %>% 
   mutate(grp = as.integer(!mday(Date) %% 5))
```